# Excel VBA Logic idea

Tags: vba, excel

My script is for tracking emails with subject and received time.
I receive 4 emails daily and I need to make reports about when email receiving.
My question is I create check box that allow which emails I want to track, but I don't know how can I make logically. First I tried , I created 15 if statements. I know it's not good so I am looking for new logic. I have attached my code below.
Please share your knowledge.

Plus, restrict method is for specified date and sender.

[image]

```
Sub GetFromOutlook()

Dim OutlookApp As Outlook.Application
Dim OutlookNamespace As Namespace
Dim OutlookMail As Variant

Dim Folder As MAPIFolder

Dim olItems As Outlook.Items
Dim myItems As Outlook.Items
Dim olShareName As Outlook.Recipient

Dim dStart As Date
Dim dEnd As Date

Dim i As Integer

Dim sFilter As String
Dim sFilterLower As String
Dim sFilterUpper As String
Dim sFilterSender As String


'========================================================
'access to shared mailbox to get items
'========================================================

Set OutlookApp = New Outlook.Application
Set OutlookNamespace = OutlookApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set olShareName = OutlookNamespace.CreateRecipient("Mailbox.teamshared@example.ca")
Set Folder = Session.GetSharedDefaultFolder(olShareName, olFolderInbox).Folders("subfolder1").Folders("subfolder2")
Set olItems = Folder.Items


'========================================================
'If check box is checked
'========================================================

dStart = Range("From_Date").Value
dEnd = Range("To_Date").Value


'========================================================
'Conditions for restrict to get items specificed date
'========================================================

sFilterLower = "[ReceivedTime] >  '" & Format(dStart, "ddddd h:nn AMPM") & "'"
sFilterUpper = "[ReceivedTime] <  '" & Format(dEnd, "ddddd h:nn AMPM") & "'"
sFilterSender = "[SenderName] = ""no-reply@example.com"""


'========================================================
'Restrict emails followed by above conditions
'========================================================

Set myItems = olItems.Restrict(sFilterLower)
Set myItems = myItems.Restrict(sFilterUpper)
Set myItems = myItems.Restrict(sFilterSender)


'========================================================
'items(emails) display in worksheets
'========================================================

i = 1

For Each myItem In myItems

     Range("eMail_subject").Offset(i, 0).Value = myItem.Subject
     Range("eMail_date").Offset(i, 0).Value = Format(myItem.ReceivedTime, "h:nn")

     'Convert size KB
     If myItem.Attachments.Count > 0 Then
     Range("eMail_size").Offset(i, 0).Value = myItem.Attachments.Item(1).Size / 1024

     Else
     Range("eMail_size").Offset(i, 0).Value = "No attached file"

     End If

  i = i + 1

Next myItem

Set Folder = Nothing
Set OutlookNamespace = Nothing
Set OutlookApp = Nothing

Else
  MsgBox "You have check at least one"
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: (a) I don't understand what you are asking. (But perhaps I just need my morning coffee.) (b) Where is the start of the `If` statement that finishes with the `Else` `MsgBox "You have check at least one"` `End If` statements?

Comment: There's nothing in your description or in your code which clarifies exactly how the different checkboxes are related to the emails you're trying to track.  How are they related?  Maybe try to explain how you'd select the mails if you were doing this manually.

Comment: Sorry for not clear, my macro is to get email's subject and received time to save Excel within specified date and specified subject which contains <V8> as option 1, <V9> as option 2, <SIS> as option 3 and <UAT> option 4 in subject. Let's say My client wants to emails of V8 or they want to V8 and UAT or all. what features can I use? The above code is not including options. The code is just getting emails which are in specified date and all subject of option1, option2, option3 and option4. It can't get emails what clients want.